# XPath use contains when full value not known

Tags: xpath

If i have the following string which is an attribute of a node:

123456-abc-123456

and the abc section can be different i.e.

```
123456-def-123456
123456-gef-123456
123456-123-123456
```

How can i check for that using the contains of xpath?

obviously the difficult part (or impossible part? ) is that the middle section is unknown

Answer (score 0):

if your xml is:

```
<a attr="123456-something-123456"/>
```

Using XPath 1.0 you can match `attr` like that:

```
/a/@*[starts-with(.,'123456-') and substring(.,string-length(.)-6)='-123456']
```

Using XPath 2.0, it's more straightforward due to all the new functions on strings. For example:

```
/a/@*[matches(.,'^123456-.*-123456$')]
```

Hope this answer your question.